# Error de verificación de integridad al actualizar Nextcloud

Tags: ubuntu, nextcloud

Al actualizar Nextcloud a su versión 12.0.3 en los avisos de seguridad me avisa de que "Algunos archivos no han superado la comprobación de integridad". 
Voy al enlace que me indica para ver más información sobre el problema y me sale esto:

> Información técnica
>
> =====================
>
> La siguiente lista cubre qué archivos han fallado en la verificación
>   de integridad. Por favor lee la documentación vinculada anterior para
>   obtener más información sobre los errores y cómo solucionarlos ellos.
>
> Resultados
>
> =======
>
> - núcleo
>
>   - EXTRA_FILE
>
>     - lib / private / oc_tmp_hMWWVJ-folder / .htaccess
>
> Salida sin procesar
>
> ==========
>
> Formación
>
> ```
> (
>
>  [core] => Matriz
>
>         (
>
>             [EXTRA_FILE] => Matriz
>
>                 (
>
>                     [lib / private / oc_tmp_hMWWVJ-folder / .htaccess] => Matriz
>                         (
>                             [esperado] => 
>                             [actual] => 59fae9bd43c1a7754899d925ca1138b99356100f160a3e491094b27401934750ef2a8a43ca8486e1007bdf674aa5bd45df9067dd050380672a29985a3ddf3887
>                         )
>
>                 )
>
>         )
>
> )
> ```

Entonces yo mire, en mi servidor Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, la ruta del `.htaccess` que me indica (`lib/private/oc_tmp_hMWWVJ-folder/.htaccess`) para borrarlo como indican en los demás foros, mi sorpresa fue que esa ruta no existe.

¿Qué puedo hacer?

Comment: Hola, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] donde encontrarás información sobre como escribir tus preguntas para que sean mejor recibidas por la comunidad. Por ejemplo, dales un formato que las haga más fáciles de leer y añade enlaces a las referencias que citas.

Comment: Por cierto, `oc_tmp_hMWWVJ-folder` no parece el nombre de un directorio real, sino un patrón de nombre que se generará a partir de la fecha en la que se realizó la accción.

Answer (score 0):

Me paso algo similar pero usando OwnCloud
Basta con seguir la documentación del sitio de Owncloud y se resuelve
https://doc.owncloud.org/server/9.0/admin_manual/issues/code_signing.html#fixing-invalid-code-integrity-messages

Comment: Hola Zydecic, aunque el enlace que pones puede contener la respuesta a la pregunta, no es suficiente para responder. Imagina que el enlace cambia o se rompe, entonces tu respuesta dejaría de tener sentido. Además, dentro de ese enlace se muestran diferentes soluciones, ¿cuál es la que debe seguir? Te recomiendo que leas [answer] y que edites tu publicación para poner la información relevante a tu respuesta.

Comment: La solución que plantean ahí es eliminar el archivo, el cual no existe en mi servidor.